# Why does this Apache Camel intercept not work?

Tags: java, apache-camel, intercept

I have a main route builder:

```
public class MainRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("activemq:a.out").to("activemq:b.in");

        from("activemq:b.in").bean(MainMessageConsumer.class);
    }
}
```

I have a second "intercept" route builder:

```
public class InterceptRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        interceptSendToEndpoint("activemq:a.out").to("activemq:c.in").skipSendToOriginalEndpoint();

        from("activemq:c.in").bean(InterceptMessageConsumer.class);
    }
}
```

Both of which are registered to the CamelContext (MainRouteBuilder is registered first, and InterceptRouteBuilder second). However, when I send a message to "activemq:a.out" via:

```
public class App {

    @Produce(uri="activemq:a.out")
    private Producer producer;

    public void run() {
        producer.request("hello");
    }

}
```

The message still arrives on MainMessageConsumer instead of being intercepted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be that if you create your producer using the @Produce annotation, then it won't be intercepted. Whereas if I put:

```
@Bean
public ProducerTemplate producerTemplate() {
    return camelContext().createProducerTemplate();
}
```

In my application config, and use that instead then it does get intercepted. Not sure if this is the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Produce is initialized before the routes, and you have defined the endpoint it should use, which is not intercepted at the time of initialization. The producer template you create have no endpoint uri set, and thus the endpoint is looked up at runtime at first request, and that endpoint has now been intercepted

Comment: I have logged a ticket to improve this so we initialize routes and other resources before starting the producers/consumers on POJO injected, then the interceptors should work - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8491

Answer (score 5):

The interceptor only applies for all routes in the same route builder class. If you want it to work on both, then create a base class, and put the interceptor there, and let the other routes extend your base class, and call its super in the configure method (eg OO inheritance)

Comment: Is this strictly true, or that in most cases it wont work unless they are in the same routebuilder? I ask because a friend has just shown me an example where they have a bunch of routes defined in xml config which he is intercepting with a route defined in a java routebuilder.

Comment: The camel docs also say that "The interceptSendToEndpoint is dynamic hence it will also trigger if a dynamic URI is constructed that Camel was not aware of at startup time."

Comment: see answer posted above